# sharepoint calculated column returning funny numbers

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I was working on a SharePoint calculated column with an if statement. The formula shows below:

```
if([Unit_Cost]<1000,"ZLP1",if(or([Asset_ClassCode]=240,[Asset_ClassCode]=200,[Asset_ClassCode]=298,[Asset_ClassCode]=860,[Asset_ClassCode]=880),"ZSTT","ZDV2"))
```

However, the column is not showing the correct info:

[image]

Where do these numbers come from?

Even if I just type `=[Unit_Cost]` in the formula, it is still giving me those funny numbers, so I am sure it is not because of my formula

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that your column [Unit_Cost] contains a number.

However, when you created your column, is the type of information "Number(1;1,0;100)"?

Comment: No, the unit cost column formula is =Amount/Qty. should I covert them into numbers?

Comment: You're about to create a column [Dep_Key_Tax] which is calculated field.
hat type of information is your [Unit_Cost]?


Try to use "single line of text data" for Dep_Key_Tax

Comment: Thanks, I have found the solution, just need to re-enter the AssetClasscode.